# Flush previous Retrofit responses

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

In my Android app I need to download metadata for some files from a XML API.
I am using RetroFit to handle the requests that I've implemented as asynchronous ones, in the Callback I parse the XML and save in a file the data I need.

When I need to get info for many files, I get `OutOfMemoryError` and analyzing the heap with MAT, I discovered that XML body of previous responses is still there. Is there any way to force the app to flush the already used XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I found a solution:

By default, the `OkHttpClient` uses a memory cache implementation for `HttpResponseCache`, switching to a disk implementation I was able to run 10000 requests without getting any `OutOfMemory` error.

I have looked at [this](https://github.com/swankjesse/android-http-examples/blob/master/http/src/main/java/com/publicobject/http/cache/OkHttpExample.java) example and edited the following lines to use Android internal storage:

```
File cacheDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), "okhttp-cache");
cache = new HttpResponseCache(cacheDir, 10L * 1024 * 1024);
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setResponseCache(cache);
```